# Why the dynamic copy of dynamic array is entered not fully and with mantisses?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have made a dynamic copy of dynamic array, and the elements of the copy are not fully outputed. Also some numbers are printed with the wrong format.

My code:

```
// the function which outputs the elements of the array
void array_transform (double* num_array_1) {
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(num_array_1); i++)
{
    cout << num_array_1[i] << endl;
}
// the code creating the copy
double* num_array_1 = new double[n];
memcpy(num_array_1, num_array, 4 * n);
```

The original array elements:

```
Array elements:
i       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
Number  42      68      35      1       70      25      79      59      63      65
```

The output of the copy:

```
42.00
68.00
35.00
1.00
70.00
-6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00
-6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00
-6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00
```

Please tell me why this is happening and how to fix this bug.

Comment: You probably missed the fact that `sizeof(num_array_1)` just gives you the size of that pointer variable itself (which is usually 8 bytes on modern architectures), and not the size of whatever you've been allocating before the function call. You need to keep track of that using a separate parameter, or simply use `std::array` or `std::vector`, which already do that correctly.

Comment: Also `4 * n` --> `sizeof(double) * n`.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` is risky because you can get the size to copy wrong. This is the error you have made.

The correct code is

```
memcpy(num_array_1, num_array, sizeof(double) * n);
```

But a better way to copy is to use `std::copy` because with `std::copy` you don't have to specify the size of the element being copied. Here's how to copy your array with `std::copy`

```
#include <algorithm>

std::copy(num_array, num_array + n, num_array_1);
```